# Rewrite link on other field in Views

Tags: 7, views, entities, uri

I'm using Drupal 7 and Clean theme. My main module is Views. And created 2 field in a content type and listed via Views on page.

I want, rewrite a field link on a other field.

e.g.
My Field:

Head: Content Head
Link: www.site.com

When click content head go to www.site.com

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have two fields, title and link, in your view. Click the title field and exclude from display so it doesn't show. Then click the link field and rewrite results. Under rewrite results I think you can check BOTH "Rewrite the output of this field" and "Output this field as a link". In rewrite results text box, put in the replacement pattern [title] and in link path [link] (you can get a full list of replacement patterns below).

If that doesn't work just do a simple href in the rewrite results text box:

```
<a href="[link]">[title]</a>
```